# Simple pole of the resolvent of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

I am writing my essay, but I have a problem about the definition of a concept that I cannot see anywhere.

If we have a linear operator $T$ whose resolvent is $R(\lambda, T)=(\lambda I-T)^{-1}$.

(1) What is exactly the resolvent of the resolvent of a linear operator?

(2) When does one say that it is simple?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might have to define a few more terms. A linear operator can be _semisimple_: this is essentially another name for diagonalisability. On the other hand, if you view $R(\lambda, T)$ as a function of the complex variable $\lambda$, you can start talking about where this function has poles. It is known that if all the poles of this function are simple, $T$ is diagonalisable.